# Express-busboy npm create folder in public directory ExpressJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

In my controller, when I try to readFile send from browser by AJAX, suddenly 1 directory created into my public folder with something like

> '3d6c3049-839b-40ce-9aa3-b76f08bf140b' -> file -> myfile

```
exports.assetAdd = function(req, res) {

    var d = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
    var f = req.files.file;
return ;
    //here i can see my unwanted created directory

    // Create S3 service object
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({
        apiVersion: '2017-03-01'
    });


    // console.log("file",f)
    fs.readFile(f.file, function(err, data) {
        return res.json(data);
```

How to remove this?

Comment: Have you tried with `fs.readFile(f, function()...` instead of `f.file` ?
You call .file when you declare f variable

Comment: The directory is created, most likely, not as a result of `readFile`, but rather as a temporary storage by multipart middleware you use (which populates `req.files.file`).

Comment: Hmm I am using express-busboy @SergeyLapin

Comment: As per docs (https://github.com/yahoo/express-busboy#file-uploads) the default temp folder is `os.tmpdir()/express-busboy/<uuid>/<the field name>/<filename>`, which looks similar to what you have. Check what's in the `path` property for a relevant `.extend` call. @A.J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is issue with the package, Already opened issue

https://github.com/yahoo/express-busboy/issues/16